# profitableness - profitability - profit

Tags: meaning

Can you clearly explain the difference between the three? profitableness -  profitability - profit.

While I can see the difference between PROFIT and PROFITABILITY, I have no idea what the difference between **profitableness** and **profitability** is.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference. **Profitableness** is derived from **profitable** in the standard way of creating nouns from adjectives, but it sounds rather clumsy, so **profitability** is preferred.

Comment: The important difference is that [nobody uses "profitableness" anymore](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=profitability%2Cprofitableness&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprofitability%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprofitableness%3B%2Cc0). Before looking it up just now, I wouldn't have said it was an English word, and my browser's spell checker agrees.

Comment: @gotube - Yes, I was surprised to find it in dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Profit is an absolute amount, whereas profitability is relative. Profitability occurs after profits, the word denotes the ability to make profits. Profit is the outcome that can be explained as the results of a transaction. The notable difference is that profitability explains the presence of profits, profitable however is another activity that has the capacity to earn profits

Comment: I up voted. But you say nothing about profitableness.

Comment: Not a bad answer, but it could do with one or more examples of the use of the three words to clarify their differences. Something like these (but you may do better!)   
I made a **profit** by selling a book for more than I paid for it.  
Selling a book for more than I paid for it is a **profitable** transaction.  
The **profitability** of a business is a measure of how much money it makes.